# Consider a set $S$ of unit vectors in $\mathbb R^2$ such that $\left<x,y\right>=-\frac12$ if $x,y\in S,x\ne y$.

Tags: linear-algebra, matrices, inner-products

This is a question from an entrance exam paper.

Consider a set $S$ of unit vectors in $\mathbb R^2$ such that $\left<x,y\right>=-\frac12$ if $x,y\in S,x\ne y$.Then it is necessarily true that

1. the set S is linearly independent
2. the set S generates $\mathbb R^2$
3. the set S is either linearly independent or generates $\mathbb R^2$
4. if the set S is linearly independent then $S$ generates $\mathbb R^2$

(Choose correct option(s))

My attempt so far:

I took $\{x_1,x_2,...x_n\}$ as a finite subset of $S$ and considered $\displaystyle \sum_{i=1}^nc_ix_i=0$ Now taking inner product with each $c_j\forall j\in \{1,2,..,n\}$ we have $c_j-\frac12\displaystyle \sum_{i\ne j}c_i=0\Rightarrow -2c_j+\displaystyle \sum_{i\ne j}c_i=0 \forall j\in \{1,2,..,n\}$

So in matrix form we have$Ac=O$

where $A=\begin{pmatrix} -2 & 1 &\cdots &1 &1 \\ 1 & -2 & \cdots &1 &1 \\ \vdots & \vdots &\ddots &\vdots&\vdots\\1&1&\cdots&1&-2\end{pmatrix}$, $c=\begin{pmatrix} c_1 \\ c_2 \\ \vdots\\c_n\end{pmatrix}$,$O=\begin{pmatrix} 0\\ 0\\ \vdots\\0\end{pmatrix}$

Thus if $A$ is invertible then clearly 1. is true.But I don't know how to show it and going for a row reduction seems very tedious for me.So I can't proceed anymore. Also I have no idea about rest of the options.

I apologise because I can't show much effort,but I am totally stuck here.

Please help me. Thnx in advance.

Comment: Please review how you stated option (4).

Comment: Your set up is unclear to me where doe $x$ and $y$ lie ? Is $S$ a set of pairs ?

Comment: @TomCollinge sorry..corrected

Comment: @ReneSchipperus This is wht written in the exam paper exactly.I think x,y are unit vectors from $\mathbb R^2$ satisfying the given condition

Comment: Note that, if $x$ and $y$ are unit vectors, $<x,y>=cos(\theta)$, where $\theta$ is de angle between the vectors

Comment: @dgrasine517 So angle between x and y is $\frac{2\pi}{3}$?How to proceed then?

Comment: @usermath yes, as user1337 said in the answer

Comment: @dgrasines517 yes I got it

Answer (score 1, accepted):

An empty set of vectors is linearly dependent (there is no non-trivial combination of vectors = 0 because there are no vectors), but doesn't span (generate) $R^2$.

A set with one (non-zero) vector is linearly independent, but doesn't span $R^2$.

A set with 2 vectors is linearly independent (else inner product is +/- 1) and therefore spans $R^2$.

A set with more than 2 vectors in $R^2$ cannot be independent, but spans $R^2$.

So looking at these four cases it is true that S is linearly independent and/or spans $R^2$. Check the wording of option (3) in your question: if this can be an *inclusive* or (i.e. and/or) , then it is true.

Comment: Actually a set with one (non-zero) vector is linearly independent, so my answer is only correct for 0 or 2 or more vectors in S. If S contains exactly one (non-zero) vector then it is linearly independent and does not generate $R^2$ so in fact **none** of the answers is true for every possible set S.

Comment: Yes that's true,if S has only one vector then there is a problem with the options.Your answer (along with this comment) clarifies every possibility.Thank you for giving your valuable time.

Comment: Embarrassingly there is another error in my answer, that an empty set is in fact linearly independent. See http://en.wikibooks.org/wiki/Linear_Algebra/Definition_and_Examples_of_Linear_Independence, example 10 or Google keywords "empty set vector independent". I've modified my answer accordingly, and also suggested an interpretation of the question.

Comment: Thank you again for your modification.Your answer and modification have really helped me to understand linear independence and dependence.And I have checked the wording of the question,thus is exactly same what I written.But the understanding I gained from your answer is far more important and useful for me than the wording of the question.Thank you again for helping me.

Comment: For you to conclusively eliminate item $(1)$, you need to give an example of a set of three or more vectors. After all, the possibility that more than one item is correct was not excluded by whoever asked the question.

Answer (score 1):

If $|S|\le 1$, the inner product condition is vacuously true.  This set does not span $\mathbb{R}^2$.

If $|S|>1$, let  $x,y\in S$.  These two  cannot be linearly dependent, because then $x=-y$ and $\langle x,y\rangle=-\langle x,x\rangle=-1\neq 1/2$.  Now $S$ spans $\mathbb{R}^2$ by a dimensionality argument.

Comment: But if |S| > 2 then they must be linearly dependant by dimensionality ?

Comment: Yes, sure. But still any two of them are linearly independent and hence generate $R^2$.

Comment: @vadim123 Thnx for your help.

Comment: @vadim123 what is dimensionality argument?can you please explain sir?

Comment: The dimension of $\mathbb{R}^2$ is 2.  Hence the dimension of any subspace is at most 2; if $x,y\in S$ are linearly independent then $dim(Span(S))\ge 2$.

Comment: Yes, but the condition in the options is not that x, y are linearly independent, but that the set S is linearly independent.

Comment: Thank you so much sir.It is very much clear now.

Comment: @TomCollinge, quite so, and $S$ may be dependent or independent for $|S|>2$.  However the independence of $\{x,y\}$ is necessary to establish that they are spanning.

Answer (score 1):

**Hint:**
Using the geometric interpretation of the inner product, you have that
$$\langle x,y \rangle=\|x\|\|y\| \cos \theta=\cos \theta=-\frac{1}{2} $$
for all $x\neq y$. Thus all distinct pairs of vectors of $S$ have an angle of $\arccos \left( -\frac{1}{2}\right)=\frac{2 \pi}{3}$ between them. This means that $S$ can't have more than two vectors.

The options for $S$ are thus:

1. an empty set
2. one unit vector
3. Two unit vectors with the appropriate angle ($2 \pi/3$) between them.
4. Three unit vectors which form an equilateral triangle.